# inheritance of instance when including a file through a function in a class?

Tags: php

I am new around here and I have a quick question if anyone can help me. To keep it short I am working on a website and I have my files separated by directories and I include the files depending on the name of the page I am on. For example I have a main page dashboard.php that looks something like :

```
include $file1;
include $file2;
include $file3 etc.
```

Now I trying to use a class page that include all the files needed automatically when I construct the object. 
My problem is when I include the files with the help of the class I can't seem to find the instance of the object in my included files.
For example : `$page=new Page("Test") includes $file1,$file2` etc.... Now when I am trying to use object $page in $file1 it doesn't fiind it. 
If anyone has a solution for this problem or if you think that is a wrong way to design web pages please let me know.

It's not a problem of includes, the includes are working, I am using autoload and all that the problem is seeing objects methods in classes included through that class. Let me be more explicit :

```
main.php :

    $page=new Page("Test");

Page.class.php :
__construct($title)
{
include($file1);
include($file2);
}
$file1:
echo "test"; // working
$file2:
echo $page->getTitle() // doesn't work, don't worry about the method it exists and works
```

Comment: Make sure you're using ABSOLUTE paths to these files. Use a global or a constant to store your `SITEROOT`, then your paths should be relative to site root, rather than the individual files. This will make work easier for you going forward, as well.

Comment: Have you tried autoload? http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), the [`include()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function inherits the [variable scope](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) of the line it's included on.

I'm assuming you're currently doing something like:

```
class Page {
public __construct() {
    include($file1);
    include($file2);
}
}
```

If you need the file(s) to be accessible outside of the class you want them to be included in, you should add the includes *outside* of the class, such as:

```
include($file1);
include($file2);
class Page { ...
```

In the event you need the included files to have access to the class-instance itself (per your latest update), you would use the [`$this`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) pseudo-variable. The reason you can't use `$page` inside the included files is because `$page` hasn't been defined; the scope of that variable is inside your main.php file and any other files it includes (but no "inside" classes).

You can update your include ($file2) to use `$this` with `echo $this->getTitle()` instead of `echo $page->getTitle()` and it should work fine.

Alternatively, if you would like to use the `$page` variable instead of `$this`, you can define it such as `$page = $this;` right before you include a file that uses it like this:

```
public __construct() {
    $page = $this;
    include($file2); // file2 will now have access to a variable named $page
}
```

Comment: I don't need the files to be accesible outside the class, I want the class to be accessible inside the files.... I have something like this: main.php : $page=new Page("Test"); page.class.php : __construct($var) { include($file1);include($file2);} ; $file1 : echo "test"(it's working) but if i'm doing echo $page->getTitle() doesn't work .... how can I make the methods inside my object accessible from other files maintaining that the files are included inside the class ...

Comment: @user1569356 Check my updated answer for usage of the `$this` variable.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to automatically load class files that are needed PHP has already a function for that.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php